# How can I add an icon to the Gmail side-bar?

Tags: google-apps-script

What method do I use in a Google-apps script for Gmail to add an icon to the side-panel?

I can't seem to find any reference to it in the docs. Thanks.

[image: This bit]

Comment: What have you done? What documentation are you looking at? Do you have the add-on created and you need to put the logo or do you have to create the entire add-on?

Comment: Nothing so far. Just trying to work out what's possible. i'd hoped that image was dynamic or html so I could display a number on it indicating new activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add a side panel icon by setting the "logoUrl" property in the [manifest](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-manifests) for GSuite Add-ons. See [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons#Common.FIELDS.logoUrl).

Comment: Right ok thanks. It's a lot less flexible than I'd hoped.